# Ruby on Rails - getting a string from a field in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, forms

I have a form with several fields e.g city, note, temperature. One of them is a "City" field.

```
<%= form.text_field :city, placeholder:"City" %>
```

I would like to "take out" the name of the city and save it as a string to use it as a source for weatherforecast-temperature.
How can I make the string from this `form.text_field :city`.

Comment: could you be more specific and add more details? maybe state at what level you wanna extract the string (e.g: controller, view) and where is the source of `weatherforecast-temperature` is it another field (maybe in the form as well)?

Comment: I would like to make a something like blog from trips. There are two text_fields: one - city, second - note. But when I click to save it (send it to db) I would like to add also a temperature which is in that citi at this moment. So my idea is: take out the name of the city from >>form.text_field :city<< as a string - put it into a query to wather api (openweathermap.org) and take out only the temperature from json and only the temperature (as an integer) sent to db.  I hope it is more understandable right now.